# Blurred 75/100 DPI Xorg font packages with Webkit?

Tags: xorg, fonts, fontconfig, webkit

In web browsers using Webkit as their engine we have blurred and unclear font rendering issue in some pages such as Stackexchange, Github and some random other sites.

The problem is the fonts come with Xorg 75/100 dpi fonts packages. In the case of Stackexchange and Github it is helveticam which come with `font-adobe-75dpi` and `font-adobe-100dpi`.

Removing these packages may affect other part of system, so my question is:

- Is there any way to tell the system to load these fonts, without scaling them or not to load these font for webkit browsers?
- Does it help to solve the problem?